# How to filter multiple values from JSON and append the results to the TableView Swift4

Tags: swift, uitableview, filter, swift4

I am trying to find a solution of how to filter multiple values from a local JSON file at the same time. The values come from UserDefaults (I have a viewController that has some buttons inside, when the button is in an active state, it saves a value to UserDefaults. Which basically means user's interest). Possibly there can be more than one interest. The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "article" : [
        {
            "title" : "Basketball",
            "subtitle" : "NBA",
            "interest" : "sports"
        },
        {
            "title" : "Africa",
            "subtitle" : "Sahara",
            "interest" : "travel"
        },
        {
            "title" : "Space",
            "subtitle" : "Satelitte",
            "interest" : "science"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to filter the "interest" key and if it matches the values that are being filtered (comes from UserDefaults), then append those articles to the tableView. This should be done before the tableview loads. The variables from userDefaults:

```
let sportsInterest = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Sports") as! String // contains "sports"
let travelInterest = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Travel") as! String // contains "travel"
```

The model looks like this:

```
class Articles: Codable {
    let article: [Article]

    init(article: [Article]) {
        self.article = article
    }
}

class Article: Codable{
    let title: String
    let subtitle: String
    let interest: String

    init(title: String, subtitle: String, interest: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.interest = interest
    }
}
```

And I am parsing JSON this way:

```
private var articles = [Article]()
var fileName: String = "Tasks"

func downloadJSON() {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "json")!

    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let articleList = try JSONDecoder().decode(Articles.self, from: data)

        self.articles = articleList.article

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.articlesTV.reloadData()
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error occured during Parsing", error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` is the right keyword.

```
let sportsArticles = articles.filter { $0.interest == sportsInterest }
```

or for more criteria

```
let criteria = [travelInterest, sportsInterest]
let filteredArticles = articles.filter { criteria.contains($0.interest) }
```

If the articles are supposed to be filtered right after loading the data write

```
let articleList = try JSONDecoder().decode(Articles.self, from: data)
self.articles = articleList.article.filter { criteria.contains($0.interest) }
```

---

It might be ***unknown*** but the initializers in the classes are redundant if the class adopts `Codable` .

Comment: Alright, thanks. But where should I put this code? Should I use any "append"?

Comment: Well, that was quick and smooth. It works perfectly, thanks a lot! ;)